# Can't get ImageMapster highlight areas to toggle text blocks

Tags: jquery

Using ImageMapster's vegetable tray [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sb9j7/), when you click on an area, it displays the text associated with that area above the main image. If you click on the same area again, it deselects the area, but leaves the text above the main image. What I need is for it to turn the text on when you click on the area (like it does now), and then turn it back off when you click the same area again.  In other words, the highlighted areas need to work like toggles to turn on & off the text associated with each one.

The portion I'm trying to work with is:

```
        onClick: function (e) {

        // update text depending on area selected
        $('#selections').html(xref[e.key]);

        }
```

I tried adding

```
$('#selections').toggle();
```

into the function.  This does create a "toggle" effect, but it doesn't stay "in sync" with the highlighted area.  It simply toggles the text blocks on & off, regardless of which area you click on.

Can someone please help solve this?